# Installing AWS Glue ETL Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

**Issue**

I am facing the below error after having set up the AWS Glue Library:

```
PS C:\Users\[user]\Documents\[company]\projects\code\data-lake\etl\tealium> python visitor.py
20/04/05 19:33:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visitor.py", line 9, in <module>
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc.getOrCreate())
  File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\[company]\projects\code\aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0\PyGlue.zip\awsglue\context.py", line 45, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\[company]\projects\code\aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0\PyGlue.zip\awsglue\context.py", line 66, in _get_glue_scala_context
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

**Scenario**

I am trying to install AWS GLue ETL Library in a virtual environment using PIPENV. So I've got the below .env file with the environment variables:

```
HADOOP_HOME="C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Spark\winutils"
SPARK_HOME="C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8"
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231"
PATH="${HADOOP_HOME}\bin"
PATH="${SPARK_HOME}\bin:${PATH}"
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}\bin:${PATH}"
SPARK_CONF_DIR="C:\Users\[user]\Documents\[company]\projects\code\aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0\conf"
PYTHONPATH="${SPARK_HOME}/python/:${PYTHONPATH}"
PYTHONPATH="${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:${PYTHONPATH}"
PYTHONPATH="C:/Users/[user]/Documents/[company]/projects/code/aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0/PyGlue.zip:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

My code initially is quite simple and I am only creating the Glue Context as bellow:

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext()

glueContext = GlueContext(sc.getOrCreate())

print(glueContext)
print(sc)
```

Do you guys know what it may be this issue?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Not yet. I am going to try it in some container or something like that.

Comment: AWS has a container image for Glue out there. Maybe that it solves your problems: https://awsfeed.com/whats-new/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```py
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel('INFO')
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
spark = glueContext.spark_session()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Also, if you create new glue job it'll give you boilerplate code which solve your problem...

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.